# How to loop through an array to get the first character of each string

Tags: javascript

I'm working on extracting the first letter of the word to form an acronym. I have an array to store all the Capticalized words and what I need to do is to get those Capitalized characters.

I used array `reduce()` method to get the capital letter. But I would like to get all the acronyms formed by different numbers of the capital letter.

```
var words = ["In", "American", "Broadcast", "Company"];

var output = words.reduce((acronym, word) => {
  acronym += word.charAt(0);
  return acronym;
}, "");
```

This will produce an output `IABC`, but we know the correct acronym is `ABC`, so I am thinking can we get `C, BC, ABC, IABC` in an iteration and then get the correct acronym `ABC`?

Comment: Do you have a different array that contains acronyms you consider "correct"? Your code has no reason to know that "ABC" is correct but "IABC" is not.

Comment: Why not consider also "IBC", "IAC", "IAB", "IA", "IB", "IC"?

Comment: @CalIrvine for example, in a text file, I am able to get "ABC" as an acronym, then I need to find its explanation. And I extract this array to extract the first letter of each word in order to match ABC. So I'm thinking a way to extract a pair of acronyms and then compare

Comment: reverse array and use reduce var output = words.reverse().reduce((acronym, word) => {
  acronym += word.charAt(0);
  return acronym;
}, "");

Comment: @trincot sure, but I think to check this fractal sequence "C, BC, ABC" from the end is faster and easier to implement.

Comment: @NagaSaiA haha nice try, it returns `CBAI` instead. Great idea tho

Comment: Can you describe what you mean when you say that you can get an acronym frmo a different file but you then "need to find its explanation"? The function you're passing to `reduce` here is able to extract the acronyms you seem to want. If I'm understanding correctly, you could write a function that creates variables for both the acronyms you need, then returns the result of `acronym1 === acronym2`

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to ignore prepositions, pronouns, conjunctions or to explain what I mean is that you want to ignore some words to be a part of your acronym? if that's the case, I think you would need to have a dictionary for those words and ignore them at first place by checking if your dictionary has those words then ignore them. sorry if I got you wrong

Comment: If you want your acronyms to be processed automatically you have to write algorithm which complexity will also get you some academic degree. I can be wrong though. Anyway, if you want to avoid scientific research, you better have an array of _registered_ acronyms (like `[ 'ABC': 'American Broadcast Company', 'LOL': 'Laught Out Loud', ... ]`) and then process only acronyms that are _known_ (are in this array). About Hindreen comment: there are _irregular_ acronyms that consist of words which are not meant to be included in acronym, so you can't just ignore words from a predefined blacklist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of reversing array and using reduce with unshift array method

1. Reverse array using .reverse()
2. Loop using reduce and add first character to beginning on every iteration
3. Join on every iteration and push to result array

working code sample for reference

```js
var words = ["In", "American", "Broadcast", "Company"];
var result = []

var output = words.reverse().reduce((acronym, word, i) => {
  acronym.unshift(word.charAt(0))
  result.push(acronym.join(""))
  return acronym;
}, []);

console.log("result", result);
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/voXXYO?editors=1010